# What are some good resources to learn Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, learn-magento

What are some good resources to learn Magento 2?

I'd like a large list of resources, in order, from starting out to complete mastery, if you guys have them available.

The big thing I'd like is free resources, even if it's a hundred hour YouTube playlist, that's fine.

Just looking for resources to learn.

Comment: Videos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxbWGz6h6KNQsi2ughRUV2Q/featured

Comment: Magento docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know answer to your question cannot be unique or acceptable for all. But I want to share some links I get redirected most of the time while looking for solution to my problems.

1. **Official [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/)** is at beginning phase as Magento 2 but it is getting better everyday.
2. **Alan Storm** is the best magento [blog](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/) writer I have ever seen.
3. [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/) is consistent at it's blog publishment.
4. [Mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/) is good place to learn magento 2.
5. [Mukesh Chapagain](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/) is outstanding nepali blog writer.
6. [Cuong PHP](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVlVTjx6M6PyPHjS6FN-PHg) is new youtube channel but excellent if it comes to magento 2 coding guide I have found till now.
7. **[Cleargo/awesome-magento2](https://github.com/Cleargo/awesome-magento2) provides the links to the very useful resources like magento tools, themes, extensions, blogs, utilities and language packages.**
8. **Max Pronko's** [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxbWGz6h6KNQsi2ughRUV2Q/featured) is also good place to understand what can be done from backend and mostly without coding.

I wil come back to add more good links when I encounter them. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

A curated list of awesome Magento 2 Extensions & Resources, keeping updates.
I am not the owner, but i fork it and this repo of resource updates frequently.
Many magento developers use these links and it helps a lot.

https://github.com/Cleargo/awesome-magento2

Comment: It includes many magento2 resources :
    Tools,
    Extensions,
    Themes,
    Blogs,
    Learning,
    Platforms,
    Official Resources

Answer (score 0):

Saying that Magento is the most popular eCommerce platform in the world hardly does it justice. It’s the most common system among the Top 1000 Internet Retailer merchants. And at the same time, it’s the CMS of choice for small retailers as well. As a result, Magento leads the way in both quality and quantity. It’s all thanks to its powerful modular-based architecture and a multitude of themes that allow it to be molded into exactly what the customer wants while still retaining the entire power of its eCommerce features – support for various locations, currencies, SEO, multi-site or multi-level setup etc.
Firebear Studio
Alan Storm
Shoppimon
Inchoo
Yireo
LinkSture
MageWorx
GoMage
MageComp
DCKAP

Answer (score 0):

Magento official documentation is one of the most trustworthy source for learning Magento 2 (http://devdocs.magento.com/) but also you can try some other sources to learn Magento 2 like [Magento 2 tutorials](https://magenticians.com/magento-2-tutorials/) as well as Magento StackExchange channel and magento subreddit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link for Magento 2 Resources:

https://github.com/aleron75/mageres